# Code style for long typespecs

Tags: elixir, typespec

Which is the code style for a long typespec which exceed 80 characters length?

```
@spec function(list() | map(), list() | map(), list() | map(), list() | nil) :: map()
```

Comment: Run `mix format`, it’ll format it according to the code style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the example from Enum module. You might want to do something similar to this

> ```
> @spec chunk_while(
>           t,
>           acc,
>           (element, acc -> {:cont, chunk, acc} | {:cont, acc} | {:halt, acc}),
>           (acc -> {:cont, chunk, acc} | {:cont, acc})
>         ) :: Enumerable.t()
>         when chunk: any
> ```